# Automatically scroll to bottom of div using Tiny Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I'm coding a shoutbox and making it as user friendly as possible. It uses the [Tiny Scrollbar plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tinyscrollbar) for jQuery and I want to incorporate an extra function that will allow me to make it go to the bottom of the `div`. It should automatically scroll (possibly with a smooth animated effect) to the bottom.

Here is the actual tiny scrollbar code:

```
(function($){
$.tiny = $.tiny || { };

$.tiny.scrollbar = {
    options: {  
        axis: 'y', // vertical or horizontal scrollbar? ( x || y ).
        wheel: 40,  //how many pixels must the mouswheel scroll at a time.
        scroll: true, //enable or disable the mousewheel;
        size: 'auto', //set the size of the scrollbar to auto or a fixed number.
        sizethumb: 'auto' //set the size of the thumb to auto or a fixed number.
    }
};  

$.fn.tinyscrollbar = function(options) { 
    var oElement = null;
    var options = $.extend({}, $.tiny.scrollbar.options, options); 

    this.each(function() {  
        oElement = new Scrollbar($(this), options);
    });
    return $.extend(this, oElement);
};

function Scrollbar(root, options){
    var oSelf = this;
    var oWrapper = root;
    var oViewport = { obj: $('.viewport', root) };
    var oContent = { obj: $('.overview', root) };
    var oScrollbar = { obj: $('.scrollbar', root) };
    var oTrack = { obj: $('.track', oScrollbar.obj) };
    var oThumb = { obj: $('.thumb', oScrollbar.obj) };
    var sAxis = options.axis == 'x', sDirection = sAxis ? 'left' : 'top', sSize = sAxis ? 'Width' : 'Height';
    var iScroll, iPosition = { start: 0, now: 0 }, iMouse = {};

    function initialize() { 
        oSelf.update();
        setEvents();
        return oSelf;
    }
    this.update = function(bKeepScroll){            
        oViewport[options.axis] = oViewport.obj[0]['offset'+ sSize];
        oContent[options.axis] = oContent.obj[0]['scroll'+ sSize];
        oContent.ratio = oViewport[options.axis] / oContent[options.axis];
        oScrollbar.obj.toggleClass('disable', oContent.ratio >= 1);
        oTrack[options.axis] = options.size == 'auto' ? oViewport[options.axis] : options.size;
        oThumb[options.axis] = Math.min(oTrack[options.axis], Math.max(0, ( options.sizethumb == 'auto' ? (oTrack[options.axis] * oContent.ratio) : options.sizethumb )));
        oScrollbar.ratio = options.sizethumb == 'auto' ? (oContent[options.axis] / oTrack[options.axis]) : (oContent[options.axis] - oViewport[options.axis]) / (oTrack[options.axis] - oThumb[options.axis]);
        iScroll = (bKeepScroll && oContent.ratio <= 1) ? Math.min((oContent[options.axis] - oViewport[options.axis]), Math.max(0, iScroll)) : 0;
        setSize();
    }
    function setSize(){
        oThumb.obj.css(sDirection, iScroll / oScrollbar.ratio);
        oContent.obj.css(sDirection, -iScroll);
        iMouse['start'] = oThumb.obj.offset()[sDirection];
        var sCssSize = sSize.toLowerCase(); 
        oScrollbar.obj.css(sCssSize, oTrack[options.axis]);
        oTrack.obj.css(sCssSize, oTrack[options.axis]);
        oThumb.obj.css(sCssSize, oThumb[options.axis]);     
    };      
    function setEvents(){
        oThumb.obj.bind('mousedown', start);
        oThumb.obj[0].ontouchstart = function(oEvent){
            oEvent.preventDefault();
            oThumb.obj.unbind('mousedown');
            start(oEvent.touches[0]);
            return false;
        }           
        oTrack.obj.bind('mouseup', drag);
        if(options.scroll && this.addEventListener){
            oWrapper[0].addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
            oWrapper[0].addEventListener('mousewheel', wheel, false );
        }
        else if(options.scroll){oWrapper[0].onmousewheel = wheel;}
    };
    function start(oEvent){
        iMouse.start = sAxis ? oEvent.pageX : oEvent.pageY;
        var oThumbDir = parseInt(oThumb.obj.css(sDirection));
        iPosition.start = oThumbDir == 'auto' ? 0 : oThumbDir;
        $(document).bind('mousemove', drag);
        document.ontouchmove = function(oEvent){
            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
            drag(oEvent.touches[0]);
        };
        $(document).bind('mouseup', end);
        oThumb.obj.bind('mouseup', end);
        oThumb.obj[0].ontouchend = document.ontouchend = function(oEvent){
            $(document).unbind('mouseup');
            oThumb.obj.unbind('mouseup');
            end(oEvent.touches[0]);
        }
        return false;
    };      
    function wheel(oEvent){
        if(!(oContent.ratio >= 1)){
            oEvent = $.event.fix(oEvent || window.event);
            var iDelta = oEvent.wheelDelta ? oEvent.wheelDelta/120 : -oEvent.detail/3;
            iScroll -= iDelta * options.wheel;
            iScroll = Math.min((oContent[options.axis] - oViewport[options.axis]), Math.max(0, iScroll));
            oThumb.obj.css(sDirection, iScroll / oScrollbar.ratio);
            oContent.obj.css(sDirection, -iScroll);
            oEvent.preventDefault();
        };
    };
    function end(oEvent){
        $(document).unbind('mousemove', drag);
        $(document).unbind('mouseup', end);
        oThumb.obj.unbind('mouseup', end);
        document.ontouchmove = oThumb.obj[0].ontouchend = document.ontouchend = null;
        return false;
    };
    function drag(oEvent){
        if(!(oContent.ratio >= 1)){
            iPosition.now = Math.min((oTrack[options.axis] - oThumb[options.axis]), Math.max(0, (iPosition.start + ((sAxis ? oEvent.pageX : oEvent.pageY) - iMouse.start))));
            iScroll = iPosition.now * oScrollbar.ratio;
            oContent.obj.css(sDirection, -iScroll);
            oThumb.obj.css(sDirection, iPosition.now);;
        }
        return false;
    };

    return initialize();
};
 })(jQuery);
```

If you could modify it to do this, I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: there is now a standard method in tinyscrollbar for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.overview:first').css({top: (($('.overview:first').height() - $('.viewport:first').height()) * (-1)) });
$('.thumb:first').css({top: $('.track:first').height() - $('.thumb:first').height()});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the native jQuery animate function to achieve the smooth auto scroll. And there is no need to alter the original tiny scrollbar script.

```
//Get the heights of the overview and viewport
oHeight = $('.overview:first').css("height");
oHeight = oHeight.substring(0, oHeight.length-2);

vHeight = $('.viewport:first').css("height");
vHeight = vHeight.substring(0, vHeight.length-2);

//Use the height values to determine how far we need to scroll
scroll = oHeight - vHeight;

//Animate it
$('.overview:first').animate({
    top: "-"+scroll+"px"
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });

//We need to do the same work for the track
tHeight = $('.thumb:first').css("height");
tHeight = tHeight.substring(0, tHeight.length-2);

trHeight = $('.track:first').css("height");
trHeight = trHeight.substring(0, trHeight.length-2);
tScroll = trHeight - tHeight;


$('.thumb:first').animate({
    top: tScroll+"px"
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same need. To address it, add the following function into the code after the this.update function:

```
this.bottom = function(){
  iScroll = oContent[options.axis] - oViewport[options.axis];
  oThumb.obj.css(sDirection, iScroll / oScrollbar.ratio);
  oContent.obj.css(sDirection, -iScroll);
};
```

Then, on your page, add a call to bottom() after your scrollbar's update() call:

```
scrollBar.update();
scrollBar.bottom();
```

Seems to work fine for me.

Robby

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can fire down to the bottom of the scroll bar by calling {$(element).tinyscrollbar_update('bottom')}