# Tiny Scrollbar auto scroll from start?

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, tinyscrollbar

I use this script: http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
Anybody has idea how i can do that the script is running from autostart when user load page? I dont see it in options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tinyscrollbar_update()` function with a integer parameter. That will move the scrollbar to the position of the integer you passed. Using a loop, you will be able to "autoscroll" to the position you want.

Sample:

```
function autoscroll(){
    var oScrollbar = $('#scrollbar1');
    oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar();

    for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar_update(i);
    }
}

window.onload = autoscroll;
```

Comment: yeap, its working but when page is load slider is update. i just wanna do this thing slowly, in 10 seconds for example. thanks for help and sorry for english :)

Comment: @DawidGórecki Oh, I got it. If you don't really need Tiny Scrollbar, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334239/2002136) can be useful.